# Feeds import to import the contents of a .txt file into a node field

Tags: feeds

I've been using feeds import module with good success to import content from CVS files into nodes. It even works great for importing images that I place in the public:// folder.

I'd like to now import the contents of a .txt file into the body of a node. Anyone know how to do this? So basically, I'd like to my node content in the file public://content-1.txt, and then put "public://content-1.txt" into my CSV file to indicate to feeds to open up the text file and take its content and place it into a field. When I do this right now, it literally puts the text "public://content-1.txt" into the field, and not the contents of the file.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!